# how to make a sphere using Metal in Swift 2.0 for iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, metal

Does anyone know how to make a sphere using Metal in iOS?
I followed this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/81399/ios-8-metal-tutorial-swift-moving-to-3d) to learn some Metal stuffs.

But I can't quiet figure out how I would render a sphere in 3D.

Comment: I do know how! But there are several steps and many options. Please give something a try and come back with smaller and more focused questions.

Comment: It's the same as rendering cube. Just change the mesh data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the mesh data, but it'll be painstaking to do everything by hand. So in total, you have a few options:

1. You can draw a sphere in a 3D modelling program like Blender and export it as an OBJ file. Then you can use a framework like Model I/O (see the WWDC video) or even your own to read the OBJ file.
2. If you're a bit more brave and ambitious, you can try to procedurally create a vertex array of a sphere using mathematical methods. I'd say that it'll be more difficult than the first one, but hey, it's cool.
3. Type all the vertex positions by hand in the vertex array. I wouldn't recommend this as it will waste time, and you won't do much to evolve your programming knowledge.

You can probably use other methods. Depends on your creativity.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is by using Model I/O framework to create an MDLMesh to represent the sphere mesh. This can be done like this:

```
let sphereMesh = MDLMesh(sphereWithExtent: vector3(0.1, 0.1, 0.1), segments: vector2(50, 50), inwardNormals: false, geometryType: .triangles, allocator: metalAllocator)
```

For more information, you can check the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/modelio/mdlmesh/1644681-init) and also [this tutorial](https://adilpatelsblog.wordpress.com/2018/06/26/exploring-metal-part-3-model-i-o-and-texturing/).